# How to make my ios phonegap app run in simulator with xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, cordova, simulator

This is a recurring problem for me, after any sort of update I can no longer run my app in the simulator - any simulator.   Most recently I updated to phonegap 1.1.0.  Now when I run the app I only get the message Build Succeeded but no message or activity relating to the simulator, it just doesn't popup and i get no error messages. I'm not sure how I got past this after previous updates (eg to xcode 4 and to phonegap 1.0.0) but this time it seems worse.

Is there  a build setting or build phase i need to set, if so which and to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to get around this problem i had to recreate the project.   a pain given my svn setup is not very smooth.